# Can someone identify this Landau reference?

Tags: specific-reference

I'm having some trouble identifying a reference Landau and Lifshitz make in volume 3 - non-relativistic quantum mechanics - of their Course of theoretical physics. This is the page from the Oxford, Pergamon, 1977 edition:

[image]

There isn't a bibliography either at the end of the chapter or the book, and other references are usually well identified in footnotes. I know it's a long shot to identify and obtain a copy of this article (in English), but I would definitely like to have a look at it. It appears to be the original publication of Landau's method of complex-contour integration to find WKB-approximation matrix elements.

Comment: [This](http://iopscience.iop.org/1063-7869/41/6/A11) could be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called the Landau-Zener formula:

> Wittig, Curt. The Landau-Zener formula. [*J. Phys. Chem. B* **109** (2005) pp. 8428-8430](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jp040627u), [author's eprint](http://curtwittig.com/wp-content/uploads/226.-Wittig-JCPB109-8428-05pdf.pdf).

Clarence Zener found it correctly, Landau had a factor of $2\pi$ error, they were independent. There are two papers by Landau on this:

> Landau, Lev D. A theory of energy transfer on collisions. *Phys. Z. Sowjet. (Physikalische Zeitschrift der Sowjetunion)* **1** 88 (1932)

and

> Landau, Lev D. A theory of energy transfer II. *Physik. Z. Sowjet.* **2** 46 (1932).

They can both be found in Landau's Collected Papers, which may be easier to get hold of than Physik Z Sowjet.

See also [1] in the first paper above for the Zener reference.

Comment: I added an extra reference to your post rather than post a new answer so you'll get the rep - I hope you don't mind.

Comment: There are also independent papers by Dykhne on this subject but I only know they're in JETP, which I usually have some trouble finding copies of.